# When were stored procedures introduced into the SQL Server product?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a bit of a different question for you computer history buffs.  Help me settle a bet between myself and a buddy of mine:

Q: When were stored procedures introduced into the SQL Server product?  I need the year and/or version.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Ok, going back beyond SQL Server to Sybase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side note, [read this for the history of SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/euanga/archive/2006/01/19/514479.aspx) by an insider.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking about MS SQL Server, they have always been there, as they were there when Microsoft licensed the product from Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures have been around since MS acquired the product from Sybase, however the closely related user defined functions have only been in since SQL Server 2000 (which replaced SQL Server 7).  IMHO they were *the* major win on that upgrade.